# ReactJs/Bootstrap : How do I set $enable-gradients property to true?

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I want to use background gradients but need to set `$enable-gradients` property to true.

How should I do that without a `.css` file in my project?

until now I have done all formatting within my `App.js` file in `className` field of `divs` such as this:

```
<div style={{ overflowX: 'hidden' }}>
```